# if-clause in select query

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch some persons data from two tables via equi join. Some persons have address data and some have not. For those persons who haven't the `addresses_id` from table `persons` is NULL.

For all persons who have an address I do (query#1):

```
SELECT p.last_name, p.first_name, 
       a.street, a.house_nr, a.post_code, a.city 
  FROM persons AS p, addresses AS a 
 WHERE p.id=42 AND a.id=p.addresses_id;
```

For all persons without address data I do (query#2):

```
SELECT p.last_name, p.first_name 
  FROM persons AS p WHERE p.id=42;
```

Is there any smooth way to put these two queries into one. Maybe with an if-clause? I don't want to check the `addresses_id` field before by myself and then execute query#1 or query#2.

I'm using MySQL with InnoDB engine.
Thanks.

Comment: Use an outer join

Comment: Do you have an example for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
  p.last_name, 
  p.first_name, 
  a.street, 
  a.house_nr, 
  a.post_code, 
  a.city 
FROM persons AS p
LEFT JOIN addresses AS a 
WHERE p.id=42
```

Comment: Thanks. Really simple, outer join was the keyword I was looking for.

Comment: I tried bro but I haven't enough rep ;)

Comment: No problem mate. Glad to help you... :-)